# "show option all" on list categories doesn't display taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, categories

I have a `wp_list_categories` list set to display my custom taxonomy.

Everything works fine, and now I want to add a `show_option_all` link.

However, when the link is clicked it displays all *default* post type posts and *none* of the custom taxonomy. Obviously, the intent is to display all of the posts in this taxonomy, and only those.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'design_asset', 'show_count' => 1, 'taxonomy' => 'asset_type', 'show_option_all' => 'Show All');
wp_list_categories($args);
```

Can this work?  How?

Comment: `post_type` isn't and argument supported by `wp_list_categories`

Comment: Yes, but the category list is correctly displaying the number of custom posts with the taxonomy and clicking the link correctly filters them.  All that _doesn't_ work is the show all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_list_categories()` is an odd function in that it's uniquely useful in certain situations with custom taxonomies but it was originally written before they even existed. (It was introduced in 2.1 and the `taxonomy` attribute was added in 3.0 ([source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Changelog)).)

What you're seeing is a known issue with an [associated bug report](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21881) (filed two years ago, last activity four months ago). If you [look at the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L511), you can see that the link is hard-coded to go to the `page_for_posts` page. So for now, you're looking for a work-around.

As @tomas-cot notes in [their comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158565/show-option-all-on-list-categories-doesnt-display-taxonomy/158569#comment228712_158565), the `post_type` argument in your code snippet isn't a valid argument for `wp_list_categories()`. However, I think what you're intending is for the `show_option_all` link to go the Post Type Archive page of your CPT.

You could do this with a walker class or maybe hacking the `title_li` argument, but since you have to wrap the function in `<ul>` tags anyway, I'd recommend the following (untested) code:

```
<?php
$list_cat_args = array(
    'show_count' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => 'asset_type',
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0 /* title attr bad for accessibility! */
);
// get the post type archive link
$all_posts_url = get_post_type_archive_link( 'design_asset' );
?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $all_posts_url ); ?>">Show All</a></li>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $list_cat_args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: It barfs on `post_type_archive_link`; it should have been `get_post_type_archive_link`.  Otherwise, it works, thank you.

Comment: Only issue is I would need the all_posts_url to be the _taxonomy_ archive page, not the _post type_ archive page.  I found `get_term_link` but I had some questions about how to use this in my case...

Comment: There isn't an archive page for an entire taxonomy, there are only archives for taxonomy *terms* and post types. I suspect the post type archive is the closest you can get.